# Mark bad blocks as unusable on NTFS using linux

Tags: linux, ntfs, bad-sectors, fsck, bad-blocks

one of my laptops are using windows and after a certain impact it doesn't boots up anymore, I figured the disk might've been damaged. So I've launced live Kali linux and scanned it with **badblocks** (like in this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/37659/the-beginners-guide-to-linux-disk-utilities/)) and found ten thousand of them (bad blocks). Now, how can I mark those blocks as unusable, because it seems that **fsck** doesn't work on **NTFS.**

```
badblocks /dev/sda > ~/bad_blocks
```

Comment: Thousands of bad block means with all the probability that your HDD is gone (or is running away really well). BTW it seems there is a solution in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/403434/196535) or better in the answer, as said in one answer here below too...

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that won't help you get it to boot anyway. Most likely there are critical system files in those damaged blocks, and you cannot access those.

Your HD cannot be used anymore. The best you can do is to use `ddrescue` or similar tool to make a complete copy of the hard disk or what can be accessed from it to a file on another hard disk, and then use data recovery software on that hard disk image file.

Comment: What I meant to do is to fix the bad blocks and then reinstall the windows there. Why my HDD cannot be used? I once had another disk with bad sectors, i wiped out them and the disk was functioning normally.

Comment: Once bad sectors have appeared, there is no guarantee that there won't be more. If you are happy to live with unreliable hardware, then you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any publicly available Linux tool that supports this. It's in the plans for `ntfsck` from *ntfsprogs*, the most advanced publicly available package for NTFS (see `ntfsprogs\ntfsck.c` in [its source](http://www.tuxera.com/community/open-source-ntfs-3g/)), but that's about it. <sub>(You might be able to contract the developers to implement this for you. This isn't so hard technically, just time and effort.)</sub>

So, your best bet for now is to boot from a Windows live media ([MS DaRT](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/hh826071.aspx) is the official one for repair tasks) and run `chkdsk /r`.

I also succeeded in booting from a Linux Live CD, sharing the block device with Samba, then mounting and checking it over the network from a Windows machine with [ImDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/).

Alternatively, [How to unmark an NTFS cluster as bad?](https://superuser.com/questions/693400/how-to-unmark-an-ntfs-cluster-as-bad/994420#994420) outlines how to do this by hand. Basically, it's editing NTFS metadata in a hex editor.

Answer (score -2):

All the bad blocks must be in one place as a scrach on the hard drive.
So, try to recover everything you can and make 2 partitions around the faulty area.

Comment: how to know the range of disk to be quarantined?

Comment: Divide et impera method and a disk bad scanner aiomei easeus etc.
You make partitions on the whole drive and scan them for bads and the bads must be in one of them.you delete that partition and make 2 Partitions from that space and so on.
You should use this method because the scan will probably get stuck in that area.

Comment: @user305645 Untrue. This is far from being the only cause for bad blocks.