# How to force Remap Current Pending Sector Count

Tags: hard-drive, sata

My Laptop Hard Drive Crystal Disk Info - Caution then I found out that there is a Current Pending Sector Count is this drive ok? Can I force remap it? on Windows or Linux?

I tried WDC Data Lifeguard or even windows `chkdsk /r` but no luck.

```
           Model : WDC WD5000LPVT-22G33T0
        Firmware : 01.01A01
       Disk Size : 500.1 GB (8.4/137.4/500.1/500.1)
     Buffer Size : 8192 KB
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 976773168
   Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS
   Minor Version : ----
   Transfer Mode : SATA/300 | SATA/300
  Power On Hours : 8531 hours
  Power On Count : 5986 count
     Temperature : 40 C (104 F)
   Health Status : Caution
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 0060h [ON]
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : C:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 200 200 _51 000000000245 Read Error Rate
03 155 152 _21 0000000004E2 Spin-Up Time
04 _87 _87 __0 00000000368F Start/Stop Count
05 200 200 140 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 200 200 __0 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
09 _89 _89 __0 000000002153 Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 __0 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0B 100 100 __0 000000000000 Recalibration Retries
0C _95 _95 __0 000000001762 Power Cycle Count
BF __1 __1 __0 00000000065E G-Sense Error Rate
C0 200 200 __0 00000000006F Power-off Retract Count
C1 184 184 __0 00000000BDB6 Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 103 _91 __0 000000000028 Temperature
C4 200 200 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 200 200 __0 000000000001 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 100 253 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
C8 100 253 __0 000000000000 Write Error Rate
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force a remap of sectors reported in S.M.A.R.T C5 (Current Pending Sector Count)?](https://superuser.com/questions/384095/how-to-force-a-remap-of-sectors-reported-in-s-m-a-r-t-c5-current-pending-sector)

Answer (score 3):

I could be done but you probably wouldn't want to.

When an error occurs when a sector is written the drive replaces the bad sector with a spare and then rewrites the data and there is no data loss. The "Reallocated Sectors Count" is a count of these sectors. But things aren't so simple when an error occurs when a sector is read. Remapping the sector would not be a good idea because this would prevent recovery of it's data if a later read operation were to succeed. Instead the drive makes a note of the bad sector and waits for one of 2 events to occur. The "Current Pending Sector Count" is a count of such sectors.

1. If the sector is later successfully read it can be remapped with no data loss. Unfortunately you have no way of knowing when this will occur or even if it is possible. The read operation may succeed at the next attempt or it may fail after 1000 tries.
2. If the sector is later written to it can be remapped with no data loss. Unfortunately there is no way of knowing when or if this will occur. If the sector contains frequently modified data the wait may not be long. But if the sector contains a system or application executable file it may be long time before it is updated, or it may not happen at all.

Note that all of this occurs entirely within the drive with the OS having no involvement or knowledge of the operation. The drive provides no means of identifying which sectors are involved, just their number. It could probably be determined with drive specific software designed for the use of data recovery professionals. Such software is designed for professional use and priced accordingly.

With no way of knowing which sectors are involved there isn't much that software can do with them. Doing a clone backup of the drive and then restoring it would force the pending sectors to be written and allow then to be remapped. With an image backup you have no assurance that the sectors involved would be written. And the data in the bad sectors would be forever lost. And with a large drive this would take considerable time.

There really is nothing to be gained by forcing the reallocation. There is no advantage in successfully reading a remapped sector with the wrong data over failing to reading the original sector with the original data. And there is a chance it may eventually succeed if not remapped. If the sector is later written it will be remapped with no data loss.

Comment: Same issue. I have 5 pending sector on one drive, and more than 100 on an other one. Why the `badblocks -n` doesn't force the drive to remap these sectors? My counter stay at 5 even after multiple passes of badblocks -n. This command is supposed to read every sectors of the drive, writing a random value, then restoring the original data.